# how to define indexing for a sqlite table with windows azure mobile services sqlite store

Tags: sqlite, azure, synchronization, azure-mobile-services

I have a windows mobile services with a table containing productid and productname. I'm using azure mobile services sync service to sync data with cloud. But I couldn't find a way to define index for the table in client side.

```
public class Product
{
    public string id;
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ProductCode")]
    public int ProductCode{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ProductName")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

And I define the table as

```
var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("sqlite.db");
store.DefineTable<Product>();
```

Now how do I define index in the sqlite table.? I couldn't find any way in msdn or any other forum.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I haven't found any docs explaining that. But I did it manually and  it worked for me. Here are the steps:

1. First install this Nuget Package ([SQLite.Net PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/)).
2. After creating your SQLite tables, create indexes on the tables and columns you want.

Code Example

```
private async Task InitLocalStoreAsync()
{
    var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("sqlite.db");
    store.DefineTable<Product>();
    await App.MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);

    // Create a new connection 
    using (var db = DbConnection)
    {
        //Adding index, say you want to add index for ProductCode column
        //Add index, table and column names respectively 
        db.CreateIndex("IX_Product_ProductCode", "Product", "ProductCode"); 
   }
}

private static SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection DbConnection
{
   //Here I'm using UWP, if you are using other platforms
   //you have to change platform and database path.
   get
   {
       return new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(
                new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(),
                System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "ipglocalstore.db"));
    }
}
```

If you are using SQLite with UWP, have a look at [this article](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/09/08/Using-SQLite-on-the-Universal-Windows-Platform.aspx).